# Integral from $0$ to $\pi/2$ of $\tan x/(4\ln(\tan x)^2 +(\pi)^2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\tan(x)}{(2\ln(\tan(x)))^2 + \pi^2}dx$$ 
I have solved it as such: 
$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\tan(x)}{(2\ln(\tan(x)))^2+\pi^2}dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)}{(2\ln(\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}-x)))^2+\pi^2}dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\cot(x)}{(2\ln(\tan(x)))^2 + \pi^2}dx$$
$$2I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\tan x+\cot x}{(2\ln(\tan x))^2 + \pi^2}dx$$
$$I=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{tan x+\frac{1}{tan x}}{2((2\ln(\tan x))^2 + \pi^2)}dx$$$$=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{\tan^2x+1}{2\tan x((2\ln(\tan x))^2 + \pi^2)}dx$$

putting $t= \tan x$, we get $dt=\sec^2x$ dx

$$=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{2t(2\ln(t))^2 + \pi^2)}dt$$
 now putting $\ln(t)=u$, $\frac{1}{t}dt=du$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2((2u)^2 + \pi^2)}du=\left[\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{2u}{\pi})}{4\pi}\right]_{-\infty}^\infty=\frac{1}{4}$$
 *Is this correct and are there any other methods?*

Comment: @TonyK $(2\ln(\cot x))^2=(-2\ln(\tan x))^2=(2\ln (\tan x))^2$

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is correct. Here is an alternative solution, which is basically the same as yours but less tricky.

Denote the original integral by $I$ and put $y=\tan x$, then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{ 4\log^2y+\pi^2 } \frac{y}{1+y^2} \mathrm d y.$$
Now put $z=\log y$, then
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4z^2+\pi^2   }\frac{e^{2z}}{1+e^{2z}}  \mathrm d z.$$
Put $w=-z$ and hence
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4w^2+\pi^2}\frac{e^{-2w}}{1+e^{-2w}}  \mathrm d w=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4w^2+\pi^2}\frac{1}{1+e^{2w}}  \mathrm d w.$$
Therefore
$$2I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4z^2+\pi^2   }\frac{e^{2z}}{1+e^{2z}}  \mathrm d z+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4w^2+\pi^2}\frac{1}{1+e^{2w}}  \mathrm d w=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty } \frac{1}{4z^2+\pi^2   }\mathrm d z.$$

Comment: you can directly take y = log(tanx)... makes it a little shorter and easier to understand